# serving an image with python and flask not working

Tags: python, flask

I reduced the code for this to, I think, minimum while trying to get it to work:
The python:

```
#!/usr/bin/env python
from functools import wraps
from flask import Flask, render_template, session, request, redirect, url_for
from flask_socketio import SocketIO, emit, join_room, leave_room, \
    close_room, rooms, disconnect


async_mode = None

app = Flask(__name__)
app.config['SECRET_KEY'] = 'secret!'
socketio = SocketIO(app, async_mode=async_mode)

@app.route('/')
def index():
    return render_template('index_test.html')


if __name__ == '__main__':
    socketio.run(app, debug=True)
```

The html:

```
<!DOCTYPE html>
<html lang="en">
<head>
    <meta charset="UTF-8">
    <title>Title</title>
</head>
<body>
    <img src="{{ url_for('index') }}bulboff.gif"/>
    <p>"{{ url_for('index') }}" <p>
</body>
</html>
```

The image is in the static folder.

And it gives this error:

"GET /bulboff.gif HTTP/1.1" 404

when the page is accessed.

I've tried several things like setting the Flask default paths, without the url_for, etc, but, still no image.

What am I missing?

Comment: "The image is in the static folder."

Answer (score 1):

According to the [flask document](http://flask.pocoo.org/docs/0.11/quickstart/#static-files):

> To generate URLs for static files, use the special `static` endpoint
>   name:
>
> ```
> url_for('static', filename='style.css')
> ```
>
> The file has to be stored on the filesystem as `static/style.css`.

In your case, use `<img src="{{ url_for('static', filename='bulboff.gif') }}">`

Answer (score 0):

If You put image in the static folder, You should use something like this:

```
<!DOCTYPE html>
<html lang="en">
<head>
    <meta charset="UTF-8">
    <title>Title</title>
</head>
<body>
    <img src="{{ url_for('index') }}static/bulboff.gif"/>
    <p>"{{ url_for('index') }}" <p>
</body>
</html>
```

Alternatively, You could change application's code and add following:

```
@app.route('/bulboff.gif')
def bulboff():
    return open('static/bulboff.gif').read()
```

Comment: Hmm...I swear I tried those combinations, but, modifying the code to:

Comment: "{{ url_for('index') }}static/bulboff.gif" does seem to work.

Answer (score 0):

```
<img src="{{url_for('static', filename='bulboff.gif')}}" />
```

Try that. Your filename could be a path from the static folder. So like if you have `filename = \some\path\img.png` it will look for the img in `static\some\ath\img`